# how do I setup android sources in intellij?

Tags: java, android, ide, intellij-idea, android-source

For my project I need to be building a custom build of Android, and I'm looking to set up the source code in Intellij.

The source code is obtained from [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/source/index.html) with the [these instructions](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). I would like to modify the Java code of some of the base modules (eg. content provider), and would like to do this in Intellij since that is my main IDE for android development.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to build the whole AOSP within IntelliJ I'm afraid I can't help you - I think you'd be setting yourself up for lots of torment there.

If, on the other hand, you just want to modify apps with it, then the easiest way I found to set up IntelliJ to do dev work on the Android source was to copy the `.classpath` file from development/ide/eclipse to the root directory, and then to have IntelliJ use it's "Build over existing eclipse structure" feature - it takes a long time but all of the apps I'm working in seem to load dependencies, etc just fine.